# fetch geometries of a composite object

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

How can one fetch geometries of composite objects?

Steps :

1. Load a model in viewer.
2. Select an composite-object(icon: `Composite Object`, dbid: `1234`) of viewer.
3. Now, How can I get geometries(icon: `Geometry`) of this composite objects?

Note: The current solution I have is to iterate the following ids incrementally until I find a next `composite-object`, which is generally the case.

[json-file for properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83joK.png)

Comment: can you add a print-screen of what you mean by `icon`?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves Here is properties ; fifth element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/83joK.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to search for elements where `displayName=="Icon"` and `displayValue=="Composite Object"`. If so, I would suggest:

```
viewer.search('"Composite Object"', onSuccessCB, onFailCB, ['Icon']);
```

This will search and the `onSuccessCB` function will receive an array of `dbIds` that matches the criteria.